# OpenGL is leaking memory. Which object is not being released?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, memory, memory-leaks

I'm having problems with my OpenGL rendering. The RAM memory grows absurdly up to the point the entire system freezes. I've identified that if I comment the entire render function, no memory grows at all. Therefore the problem is that my OpenGL render function might be allocating memory for something and I'm not releasing it.

Can you identify what is the problem?

PS: the thing inside the if actually runs one single time, so the allocation of memory it does, occur only one time

This is my OpenGL render function:

```
void OpenGlVideoQtQuickRenderer::render()
{
    if (this->firstRun) {
        std::cout << "Creating QOpenGLShaderProgram " << std::endl;
        this->firstRun = false;
        program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();
        //this->m_F  = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->functions();

        datas[0] = new unsigned char[width*height];     //Y
        datas[1] = new unsigned char[width*height/4];   //U
        datas[2] = new unsigned char[width*height/4];   //V

        std::cout << program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, tString2) << std::endl;
        std::cout << program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, vString2) << std::endl;

        program->bindAttributeLocation("vertexIn",A_VER);
        program->bindAttributeLocation("textureIn",T_VER);
        std::cout << "program->link() = " << program->link() << std::endl;

    }
    program->bind();


    glVertexAttribPointer(A_VER, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, ver);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(A_VER);

    glVertexAttribPointer(T_VER, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, tex);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(T_VER);

    unis[0] = program->uniformLocation("tex_y");
    unis[1] = program->uniformLocation("tex_u");
    unis[2] = program->uniformLocation("tex_v");

    glGenTextures(3, texs);

    //Y
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    //U
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[1]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, width/2, height / 2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    //V
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[2]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, width / 2, height / 2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[0]);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, datas[0]);
    glUniform1i(unis[0], 0);


    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[1]); 
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width/2, height / 2, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, datas[1]);
    glUniform1i(unis[1],1);


    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[2]);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width / 2, height / 2, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, datas[2]);
    glUniform1i(unis[2], 2);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);
    program->disableAttributeArray(A_VER);
    program->disableAttributeArray(T_VER);
    program->release();
}
```

Comment: I am willing to believe that the "First time" code is not the cause of your memory leak, BUT 1) you should still be using smart pointers for this, since there's no obvious benefit to using naked allocated memory, 2) you should include the other, surrounding code. It's possible that some other issue (like, say, this object being passed by value instead of reference) could be causing the memory leak indirectly by invalidating your assumption that this code really could only be run once. A proper [mcve] contains all the necessary information to reproduce the issue, and this isn't quite that.

Comment: @Xirema you're right, I'm going to use smart pointers, it was just a scratch. I could post a minimal complete example but I think it'd be huge :(. At least you can't see anything in render() that should be released, right? OpenGL doesn't maintain memory forever, I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is creating three new textures in each frame (`glGenTextures`) without ever releasing them (`glDeleteTextures`). Either you delete them at the end of the render method, or even better: You only create the textures once in the first block and then only upload new data to them.

Just for the records: Drawing from CPU memory by specifying the address in `glVertexAttribPointer` is only valid in OpenGL before Core profile. I highly suggest to use Vertex Buffer Objects instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try to use VBO's instead