# OpenGL strange behaviour in QT when inheriting from QQuickItem versus QQuickPaintedItem (rendering video)

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

*This question is a rewrite of [Red video on top of normal video in Qt/OpenGL using QQuickItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56640523/red-video-on-top-of-normal-video-in-qt-opengl-using-qquickitem) but with the code broken to a minimum verifiable example. However, you should see the photos of the old question because they show what happens when real video is rendered into the screen*

I have a class class called `OpenGlVideoQtQuick2` which I'm testing two possible inheritations: from `QQuickItem` versus with `QQuickPaintedItem`. I get the expected behavior (a giant red screen) when `OpenGlVideoQtQuick2` inherits from `QQuickItem`, but not when it inherits from `QQuickPaintedItem`, which is when I get a black screen with size 640x480, which is the size of the `OpenGlVideoQtQuick2` item in `main.qml`.

Here's what happens when `class OpenGlVideoQtQuick2 : public QQuickPaintedItem`
[image]

Here's what happens when `class OpenGlVideoQtQuick2 : public QQuickItem`
[image]

Here's the code:

**OpenGlVideoQtQuick2.h:**

```
#ifndef OpenGlVideoQtQuick2_H
#define OpenGlVideoQtQuick2_H

#include <QtQuick/QQuickItem>
#include <QtGui/QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QtGui/QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QtQuick/qquickwindow.h>
#include <QtGui/QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QtGui/QOpenGLContext>
#include <QString>
#include <iostream>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QMatrix4x4>
#include <QQmlListProperty>
#include <QQuickPaintedItem>


class OpenGlVideoQtQuick2Renderer2 : public QObject, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    OpenGlVideoQtQuick2Renderer2() {        
    }
    ~OpenGlVideoQtQuick2Renderer2();
    void setViewportSize(const QSize &size) { m_viewportSize = size; }
    void setWindow(QQuickWindow *window) { m_window = window; }

    QMatrix4x4 qQuickVideoMatrix;

public slots:
    void render();

private:
    QSize m_viewportSize;
    QOpenGLShaderProgram* program;
    QQuickWindow *m_window;
    GLuint unis[3] = {0};
    GLuint texs[3] = { 0 };
    unsigned char *datas[3] = { 0 };
    bool firstRender = true;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
};

//class OpenGlVideoQtQuick2 : public QQuickItem
class OpenGlVideoQtQuick2 : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
protected:
    void paint(QPainter* painter){std::cout << "PAINT BEING USED" << std::endl;};

public:
    OpenGlVideoQtQuick2();
    QMatrix4x4 getModelMatrix();

signals:
    void tChanged();

public slots:
    void sync();
    void cleanup();
    void update();//Updates the window


private slots:
    void handleWindowChanged(QQuickWindow *win);

private:
    OpenGlVideoQtQuick2Renderer2 *openGlVideoQtQuick2Renderer2;

};

#endif // OpenGlVideoQtQuick2_H
```

**OpenGlVideoQtQuick.cpp:**

```
#include "OpenGlVideoQtQuick2.h"

#define GET_STR(x) #x
#define A_VER 3
#define T_VER 4

//Simple shader. Outpus the same location as input, I guess
const char *vString4 = GET_STR(
    attribute vec4 vertexIn;
    attribute vec2 textureIn;
    varying vec2 textureOut;
    uniform mat4 u_transform;   
    void main(void)
    {
        gl_Position = u_transform * vertexIn;
        textureOut = textureIn;
    }
);


const char *tString4 = GET_STR(
    varying vec2 textureOut;
    void main(void)
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0,0, 1.0);
    }

);


void OpenGlVideoQtQuick2::update()
{
    if (window())
        window()->update();
}

OpenGlVideoQtQuick2::OpenGlVideoQtQuick2()
    : openGlVideoQtQuick2Renderer2(nullptr)
{
    connect(this, &QQuickItem::windowChanged, this, &OpenGlVideoQtQuick2::handleWindowChanged);
}


void OpenGlVideoQtQuick2::handleWindowChanged(QQuickWindow *win)
{
    if (win) {
        connect(win, &QQuickWindow::beforeSynchronizing, this, &OpenGlVideoQtQuick2::sync, Qt::DirectConnection);
        win->setClearBeforeRendering(false);
    }
}

void OpenGlVideoQtQuick2::cleanup()
{
   if (openGlVideoQtQuick2Renderer2) {
        delete openGlVideoQtQuick2Renderer2;
        openGlVideoQtQuick2Renderer2 = nullptr;
    }
}

OpenGlVideoQtQuick2Renderer2::~OpenGlVideoQtQuick2Renderer2()
{
    delete program;
}

void OpenGlVideoQtQuick2::sync()
{
    //std::cout << "sync called" << std::endl;
    if (!openGlVideoQtQuick2Renderer2) {
        openGlVideoQtQuick2Renderer2 = new OpenGlVideoQtQuick2Renderer2();
        connect(window(), &QQuickWindow::beforeRendering, openGlVideoQtQuick2Renderer2, &OpenGlVideoQtQuick2Renderer2::render, Qt::DirectConnection);
        connect(window(), &QQuickWindow::afterRendering, this, &OpenGlVideoQtQuick2::update, Qt::DirectConnection);
    }
}


static const GLfloat ver[] = {
    -1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f
};

static const GLfloat tex[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f
};

//TODO: FIX THIS https://stackoverflow.com/a/54773889/6655884
void OpenGlVideoQtQuick2Renderer2::render()
{
    int frameWidth = 1280;
    int frameHeight = 720;
    if (this->firstRender) {
        std::cout << "Creating QOpenGLShaderProgram " << std::endl;
        program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();
        //this->m_F  = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->functions();
        std::cout << "frameWidth: " << frameWidth << + " frameHeight: " << frameHeight << std::endl;
        datas[0] = new unsigned char[frameWidth*frameHeight];   //Y
        datas[1] = new unsigned char[frameWidth*frameHeight/4]; //U
        datas[2] = new unsigned char[frameWidth*frameHeight/4]; //V

        std::cout << "Fragment Shader compilation: " << program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, tString4) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Vertex Shader compilation: " << program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, vString4) << std::endl;

        program->bindAttributeLocation("vertexIn",A_VER);
        program->bindAttributeLocation("textureIn",T_VER);
        std::cout << "program->link() = " << program->link() << std::endl;

        glGenTextures(3, texs);//TODO: ERASE THIS WITH glDeleteTextures
        this->firstRender = false;

    }
    program->bind();

    QMatrix4x4 transform;
    transform.setToIdentity();
    program->setUniformValue("u_transform", this->qQuickVideoMatrix);

    glVertexAttribPointer(A_VER, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, ver);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(A_VER);

    glVertexAttribPointer(T_VER, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, tex);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(T_VER);

    unis[0] = program->uniformLocation("tex_y");
    unis[1] = program->uniformLocation("tex_u");
    unis[2] = program->uniformLocation("tex_v");

    //Y
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, frameWidth, frameHeight, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    //U
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[1]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, frameWidth/2, frameHeight / 2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    //V
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[2]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, frameWidth / 2, frameHeight / 2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[0]);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, datas[0]);
    glUniform1i(unis[0], 0);


    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[1]); 
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, frameWidth/2, frameHeight / 2, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, datas[1]);
    glUniform1i(unis[1],1);


    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[2]);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, frameWidth / 2, frameHeight / 2, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, datas[2]);
    glUniform1i(unis[2], 2);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);

    program->disableAttributeArray(A_VER);
    program->disableAttributeArray(T_VER);
    program->release();
}
```

**main.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

import OpenGlVideoQtQuick2 1.0


Grid {
    columns: 2
    spacing: 2    
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    OpenGlVideoQtQuick2 {
        width: 640
        height: 360
    }

}
```

So, I need to make my class derive from `QQuickPaintedItem`, not `QQuickItem`, and I need that black screen to not appear on top of my red screen, which is where the actual video will be loaded.

The entire project can be found here: https://github.com/lucaszanella/QQuickPaintedItemBug/tree/c9c2b23d891689a63fbaf2f014142be1f3c5ff0d, where you can compile and test. I recommend to compiling using locally installed `cmake` and `qt` folders as explained in the `Readme.md` file in github

Comment: By reading your other posts my understanding is that you want to show a video feed that fills only the top left rectangle and not the whole window, am I right?

Comment: @SilvanoCerza not only that. I want that, but if I do that by using viewport, I still get the rectangle appearing on top of my video. In this example, it's a black rectangle, but if I try ti show video, then it's a red video on top of normal video

Comment: So you want to switch between the video filling the window and the video on the corner? Do you have to use raw OpenGL calls or is the `paint` method a viable option?

Comment: @SilvanoCerza I have to use OpenGL, but I think I didn't explain exactly what I want. Right now the video occupies the entire screen just so I can see the black box that appears on top of it. However, the video should be just the size of that back box. I made it red in my example, but that red in the complete code shows video as it should, but a red video appears on top of it, as you see in the image

Comment: Thanks, that's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not expect the result of using `QQuickItem` and `QQuickPaintedItem` to be the same.

When you use `QQuickPaintedItem`, you are supposed to render the item using the `paint()` function. Since you call your `render()` function on `beforeRendering()`, then just after you do your own rendering, the `QQuickPaintedItem` will render on top of it what you should have painted in the `paint()` function.

You can prevent the `QQuickPaintedItem` from rendering the black rectangle by reimplementing `updatePaintNode()` as an empty function.

Comment: I tried as you said, look: https://github.com/lucaszanella/QQuickPaintedItemBug/commit/123149bad9bc6a8fe395c34575f11a5eb29e4487

Comment: but I still see the black box

Comment: actually the updatePaintNode function isn't being called at all, I debugged it

Comment: @LucasZanella That's because you overloaded updatePaintNode, I told you to reimplement it (ie override it)=> You must keep the same signature as the one declared in QQuickItem